# net files vs openfiles IDs

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-command-prompt

I was doing a PowerShell script for a quicker way of closing locked files on a big Windows Server 2008 R2 file server (more than 2500 files opened at this moment, and the peak hour was like 3-4 hours ago), and I'd to choose between `net files` or `openfiles`. So I went with `openfiles` as is newer and it can give the full path of the file (`net files` can do that too, but you've to query every single ID).

I was having problems with it: some files won't close. I checked with net files, and all was ok... So I've started to take a closer look, and this is (an excerpt of) what I've found:

```
C:\> net files

ID         Path                                    User name            # Locks

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3221368833 G:\Users\...                            SomeUser              3
2550215683 G:\Users\...                            SomeUser              3
3422797829 G:\Users\...                            SomeUser              0
805310474  F:\Recursos\...                         SomeUser              3
335585292  G:\Users\SomeUser\My Documents          SomeUser              0
4026636306 G:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop               SomeUser              0
2684396568 G:\Users\...                            SomeUser              0
2952839192 G:\Users\...\EXCEL\SomeFolder2016       SomeUser              0
4160993304 G:\Users\...                            SomeUser              0
1610613364 F:\Recursos\Suministros                 SomeUser              0
The command completed successfully.

C:\> openfiles /query /v

Files opened remotely via local share points:
---------------------------------------------

Hostname        ID       Accessed By          Type       #Locks     Open Mode       Open File (Path\executable)

=============== ======== ==================== ========== ========== =============== ============================================================================
MyServer        32213688 SomeUser             Windows    3          Write + Read    G:\Users\SomeUser\My Documents\[SomePath].XLS
MyServer        25502156 SomeUser             Windows    3          Write + Read    G:\Users\SomeUser\My Documents\[SomePath].xls
MyServer        34227978 SomeUser             Windows    0          Write + Read    G:\Users\SomeUser\My Documents\[SomePath].xls
MyServer        80531047 SomeUser             Windows    3          Write + Read    F:\Recursos\Suministros\[SomePath].xls
MyServer        33558529 SomeUser             Windows    0          Read            G:\Users\SomeUser\My Documents
MyServer        40266363 SomeUser             Windows    0          Read            G:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop
MyServer        26843965 SomeUser             Windows    0          Write + Read    G:\Users\SomeUser\My Documents\[SomePath].XLS
MyServer        29528391 SomeUser             Windows    0          Read            G:\Users\SomeUser\My Documents\EXCEL\SomeFolder2016
MyServer        41609933 SomeUser             Windows    0          Write + Read    G:\Users\SomeUser\My Documents\[SomePath].XLS
MyServer        16106133 SomeUser             Windows    0          Read            F:\Recursos\Suministros
```

Wait, the IDs are different... Hell, no, the `openfiles` IDs are truncated!!

So obviously for the script itself, I'm for the moment going for `net files`, get the IDs, query each single ID so I get the full path, and from there I can reuse the rest of the script.

But for the sake of my sanity: is this a bug? A feature? Windows Server 2008 R2 is not new, and I was not able to find any reference to this, not to talk about a hotfix!

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place?

Comment: To quickly find files by a part of their name (users are in fact not providing the full name), so something like:
MyScript PartialName

will give me all files with that string on their fullpath, then I select the one I want to close.

Comment: I meant why are you closing the files? Users have them open and are using them, no?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry! The problem is users forget to close the files, they leave, then colleagues from other shift come in, and they cannot edit them.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Now I understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So three years later, I've found an answer and a solution, or workaround: this is a bug of the default output of `openfiles`, which is `table`. If you specify the options `/FO CSV` or `/FO List`, IDs are complete.

Comment: Saved me hours of scratching my head. Using `/FO CSV` is great.